# Quartz triggering same instance twice

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

We are using `DisallowConcurrentExecutionAttribute` annotation inside the Java class to prevent concurrent execution of multiple instances, however, looks like Quartz has triggered twice the same instance concurrently. Please address this issue and provide us more information and fix this issue if it is a bug.

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public void execute(final JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
    logger.log(Log.DEBUG, "++++ Quartz JOB BatchJobDetector started");
    try {
        this.setJobExecutionContext(jobExecutionContext);
        boolean triggerNextJob = true;
        while (triggerNextJob) {
            TriggeredBatchProcessDTO triggeredBatchProcessDTO = getNextJob(jobExecutionContext, 0);
            if (triggeredBatchProcessDTO != null) {

                triggerJobImmediatly(triggeredBatchProcessDTO.getId(), jobExecutionContext);
                triggeredBatchProcessDTO.setState(StatusType.RUNNING);  
                triggeredBatchProcessDTO.setProcessDtTm(triggeredBatchProcessDTO.getProcessDtTm());//CRGRO022
                updateTriggeredBatchProcessDTO(triggeredBatchProcessDTO);

            } else {
                triggerNextJob = false;
            }
        }
    } catch (final UnexpectedRuntimeException e) {
        logger.log(Log.ERROR, "Error during execution of TriggeredBatchProcessDetectorJob: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        throw e;
    } catch (final Throwable t) {
        throw new UnexpectedRuntimeException(CoreExceptionId.RUN_0001_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION,
            new Object[] { "TriggeredBatchProcessDetectorJob error" }, t);
    }
    logger.log(Log.DEBUG, "++++ Quartz JOB BatchDetector finished");
}
```

Comment: It is a bit difficult to help you without versions information, code snippet triggering the issue etc ... If you want others to take time for your question, please enhance it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up quartz correctly through properties to run it into the cluster mode and I'm not sure but imho you should also use `@PersistJobDataAfterExecution` annotation. I was using clustered quartz without any problems also with depracated job implementations 
[StatefulJob](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/StatefulJob.html). You need to show us your config - [here is sample](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering) - and give quartz lib versions

Comment: we are using this annotation as well @PersistJobDataAfterExecution, I am completely new to quartz, could you please be little more specific or explain what exactly you mean by config here, quartz version is 2.2.1

Comment: If we're talking about properties I mean for instance:
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyClusteredScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
I mean configuration on database, or your JEE container